# AngularJS and URL Rewrite to HTTPS

Tags: angularjs, ssl, url-rewriting

So I have ui-router in my application and everything has been working fine.
I was asked to make the account area of the site forced HTTPS so I set up this rule:

I have a link on the main "view" that takes you to the login page and the link looks just like this:

```
<a class="link-primary" ui-sref="login" ng-switch-default>Sign in</a>
```

The state rule set up looks like this:

```
.state('login', {
    url: '/account/signin',
    params: {
        returnState: null,
        returnParams: null
    },
    templateUrl: '/assets/tpl/account/signin.tpl.html',
    controller: 'LoginController',
    controllerAs: 'controller',
    resolve: {
        pageTitle: ['PageHead', function (service) {
            service.setTitle('Kudos Sports - Login');
        }]
    }
})
```

When I click the link I get an error message:

> > XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://kudos-topspindigital.azurewebsites.net/assets/tpl/account/signin.tpl.html. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://kudos-topspindigital.azurewebsites.net' is therefore not allowed access.

I can type the url (https://kudos-topspindigital.azurewebsites.net/account/signin) and this works without any issues. I can even do it by omitting the https protocol and it will redirect with no issues, so I can only assume there is something wrong with angularJS.

Can someone help me fix my issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tbh the best way for me to do this was to set up a rule that pushed everything to HTTPS, not just the account stuff.

```
    <rule name="Redirect .com to www" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="kudos-sports.co.uk" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="kudos-sports.com" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="kudos-sportswear.co.uk" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="kudos-sportswear.com" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.kudos-sports.co.uk" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.kudos-sportswear.co.uk" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.kudos-sportswear.com" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="kudos-sports.azurewebsites.net" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.kudos-sports.com{REQUEST_URI}" />
    </rule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try add HTTP header in your server response by:

```
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"
```

This time, use server side script to return HTML instead pure html, for example, in PHP

```
<?php
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Comment: it's just HTML, there is no server side (for that bit)

Comment: Then the index html should be sent by https, not http, then all fine, just keep them in same domain and protocol

Comment: they are, that's what I don't understand